# how to read an indent-formatted json into a dictionary

Tags: python, json, dictionary, indentation

i'm trying to read a json file that's formatted in a human-readable way, with indentations and line splits. Something like this:

```
{
    "a":1, 
    "b":2, 
    "c":3
}{
    "d":4, 
    "e":5, 
    "f":6
}{
    "g":7, 
    "h":8, 
    "i":9
}
```

Going the standard way of

`json.load(file)`

results in

`JSONDecodeError: Extra data error`

Could someone please suggest a way to read this without reformatting the original file?

Comment: it is not correct JSON data. It is three JSON data in one file. Correctly it should be list with directories separated by comma - [ {...}, {...}, {...} ], and indent-formatting has nothing to do with your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Say you have the contents of the file in as the variable `contents`. You should be able to convert it into a json decodable way:

```
contents = "[" + contents.replace("}{", "},{") + "]"
```

and then do a `json.load`. Your error is happening because there isn't a comma in between each of the array elements, and there isn't brackets around the array. The indent formatting has nothing to do with it; `json.load` works with indents.

Comment: thank you. yes - ultimately this was a problem with my storing of json in the first place and was much easier resolved there by putting all incoming dictionaries in an array to maintain the structure you've described.

Comment: @konstantin Your welcome! If it helped, please accept it by pressing the green check mark to the left of the answer